# How to fetch data from my database into <td id="myId"> using php?

Tags: php, html-table, fetch

I have created a table of empty cells as follows

$sql1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM production WHERE date(productiondate)='".$today."' AND productionline=1");

```
echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Row #1</td>";
        for($i=8;$i<=20;$i++)
        {
            echo "<td id=".$i."></td>";
        } echo "<td></td>";
```

Now I want to insert values into specific cells according to their ids, but unable to do so since the following function will insert them serially.

```
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql1))
        { 

        echo "<td>".$row['productionquantity']."</td>";

        }

        echo "</tr>";
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. And please let me know if any other snippets of my code are required to get a better understanding of my motive.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any `$sql2` variable?
Because your `mysqli_fetch_array()` gets an "`$sql2` parameter.

Comment: I'm sorry, that's a typo. Its actually  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql1))

Comment: Try this: `$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql1);` and `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Comment: didnt work. the entire table vanished. what was it supposed to do?

Comment: This should be your whole function: `$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM production WHERE date(productiondate)='".$today."' AND productionline=1";` `$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql1)` and then comes the `while` function: `while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {` `echo "<td>".$row['productionquantity']."</td>"; }`

Comment: can you explain what this does? because this is exactly what i'd done but without avail

Comment: Maybe this can help more: [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Comment: Thanks man. I also need to know how to insert the fetched values in cells corresponding to the ids